# Where are the PNG files for the UI theme stored?

Tags: macos, finder, themes

I like using my Mac with the "graphite" theme, but I'd like to still keep the color "traffic light" graphics.  I remember from various theme modifiers in the past that these are simple PNG files, so I figured if I copied the color ones into the graphite directory it would use them.

I forget where in the System these files are.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/UI.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

Comment: There's no UI.bundle at that path.  I'm on 10.8.3, if it matters.

Comment: Interesting... I spend most of my time in 10.6; but, in checking a 10.8 machine, it looks like everything is in an ArtFile.bin or ArtFile200.bin (for retina macbooks?) file.   This looks like it could be useful: https://github.com/alexzielenski/SArtFileTool